# Deepset Haystack Secure Connection to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, haystack

I am trying to create a Haystack document store with Elasticsearch (run on Docker with security) but I am getting the following errors. I know I need to tell Haystack to use `https` but I couldn't find a how in the docs.  I did try specifying port 9300 and 9200.

```
document_store = ElasticsearchDocumentStore(
    host='https://localhost', 
    username= 'elastic',
    password='{PASSWORD}',
    port=9200,
    index='squad_docs'
)
```

Haystack errors in the Python console

```
ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Elasticsearch WARN in the logs

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-11-08T14:01:54.875Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/172.18.0.2:9200, remoteAddress=/172.18.0.1:56568}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[c759978b5b07][transport_worker][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"vDXCcs4uQM-gcuf5vciZkA","elasticsearch.node.id":"VunPyrAPRbG9PrLFyZ1E8w","elasticsearch.node.name":"c759978b5b07","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ElasticsearchDocumentStore` has a parameter `scheme` which you need to set to `"https"`. You might want to have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/reference/document-store-api#elasticsearchdocumentstore__init__) to see all available parameters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).